# iOS bonjour browser is not reliable

Tags: ios, xamarin, bonjour, zeroconf, avahi

I am using NSNetServiceBrowser from Xamarin (former Mono Touch) to scan for bonjour devices. This works most of the time, but there seems to be

a) a big caching issue, where it doesn't realize there are new devices
b) a problem with the WIFI, e.g. when I turn off the wifi and turn it back on then

Most of the time, the Apple Bonjour devices are found, but avahi based devices (network printers) are rarely shown in the case of a) or b).

I am aware of [NSNetServiceBrowser/Bonjour issues on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645613/nsnetservicebrowser-bonjour-issues-on-ios) by the way.

Comment: These avahi devices are found on other applications on this device? Isn't it a problem on the communication between avahi and Bonjour protocols. There may be some minor issues that are causing this. Non-avahi devices perform well on these cases?